# De Morgan´s law with subset families

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If  $F$ $\subseteq P(E)$, how can I prove $C_E(\cup_{S \in F} S)= \cap_{S \in F} C_ES$?

I know that:

$(\cup_{S \in F} S)=\{x:( \exists S \in F)(x \in S)\}$

$(\cap_{S \in F} S)=\{x:( \forall S \in F)(x \in S)\}$

but I don't know how to write this demonstration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick arbitrary $x \in (\bigcup_{S \in \mathcal F} S)^c$. This means $x \notin  S ~ \forall~ S \in \mathcal F$,thus $x \in S^c ~\forall ~ S \in \mathcal F$, hence $x \in \bigcap_{S \in \mathcal F} S^c$ or that ($\bigcup_{S \in \mathcal F} S)^c \subseteq \bigcap_{S \in \mathcal F} S^c$.

Now pick arbitrary $x \in \bigcap_{S \in \mathcal F} S^c$. Thus $x \in S^c ~\forall ~ S \in \mathcal F$ or that $x \notin S ~\forall ~ S \in \mathcal F$, so that $x \notin \bigcup_{S \in \mathcal F} S$ or $x \in (\bigcup_{S \in \mathcal F} S)^c$, so that $\bigcap_{S \in \mathcal F} S^c \subseteq (\bigcup_{S \in \mathcal F} S)^c$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in C_E(\bigcup_{S \in F} S)$. We want to show $x$ is in $\bigcap_{S \in F} C_E(S)$. So take any $S \in F$. If $x \in S$, then $x \in \bigcup_{S \in F} S$ which is a contradiction. So $x \in C_E(S)$. As $S \in F$ was arbitrary, $x \in \bigcap_{S \in F} C_E(S)$.

Let $x \in \bigcap_{S \in F} C_E(S)$. We want to show $x$ is in $C_E(\bigcup_{S \in F} S)$, so suppose it is not. Then $x \in \bigcup_{S \in F} S$ so by definition there is some $S \in F$ with $x \in S$. But then, for this $S$, we have $x \notin C_E(S)$ and this contradicts $x \in \bigcap_{S \in F} C_E(S)$. So we're done.